# Rails - how do I move a variable from one controller action to another without resetting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a variable which contains a certain date based on certain criteria, which is established in the index action of my controller:

```
def index
    if params[:y] && params[:m]
      @date = ...
    elsif
      @date = ...
    else        
      ...
```

It is a bit more complicated than the example above, but you should get the idea.
If I then want to use this variable within another action of the same controller, how do I do that? I would like it to be something like:

```
def new
  @today = see index action
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you make the date a global?

Comment: You can store the value in a hidden input and then fetch it.

Comment: @Vucko thought about it, but it is a pretty ugly solution.. maybe something more elegant?

Comment: What about [session variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)?

Comment: You can even use a [session based model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model)

Comment: Have you thought about this - you're setting the date in the `index` action of your controller. Why? What's the context for that? Can you explain why the date will be defined there? You're passing some params - can you explain these?

Comment: The answer will be to take the processing of these variables outside of the controller & into something else (a helper maybe)?

Comment: This way, the data will be available to any controller action; it will just be a case of persisting the data, which we can work out if you give us some more context

Comment: @RichPeck I see no point in overcomplicating for no reason.. I think for me it will be easier to pass a variable using the URL, or HTML5 storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is No Way.

Every request creates an instance of controller. When hitting `#index`, there is an instance. And the instance variables you defined can live there. When hitting "new", that's a new instance, the old instance variables are no longer there.

To remember something between requests, you can

1. Use query strings.
2. Use session
3. Save to db(as user preference).
4. Use cookie(not nice)

Comment: @RichPeck, would you tell? Thanks.

Comment: lol yes I was being a bit toungue-in-cheek; this kind of query needs some thought... but I can think about if you want?

Comment: @RichPeck, I see. So basically the claim is not that serious :) Never mind, and don't think too much, the current workarounds should be enough.

Comment: Billy, we always look at problems from a deeper perspective (I.E if it's not working in the controller, extract to another type of file). We never like to say "there's no way", because it's just a case of setting & persisting the data; which can be done relatively simply in Rails. The trick will be to work out how

Comment: You are talking about persisting data, not sharing instance variables as the question asked. The final problem certainly may have multiple solutions, but you have restriction on execution.

Comment: @DenisG, that's nice. Just a bit caution that localStorage is not compatible with all browsers, use that if you are okay at this point.